# Why does this site return http 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

this is my htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^slople.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.slople.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# pass the default character set
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$ index.php?slopeId=$1 [L,QSA]

    #only rewrite if it's not a file and not /login/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/community/

    #Wordpress-Regeln
    #RewriteBase /community/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /community/index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Why does the URL http://www.slople.com/deutschland/hessen/buseck/alter-steinbruch/14231?language=DE, which should match this rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$ index.php?slopeId=$1 [L,QSA]
```

return a http 404?

I thought the "[L]" would stop execution of the later rules in htaccess?

Thanks
Raphael

Comment: Just a remark for your thought on the `[L]` flag: The `[L]` flag ends the application of rules _for this request_, not in general. If you rewrite the request to hit the same server again the rewrite process is started again.

Comment: ok, but still, the rewritten URL should not return a 404, after all, the site loads correctly?

Comment: You have two conditions in the middle of your file, don't seem like they belong

Comment: Even if I remove every rule but the first, it still returns a 404

Comment: The `[L]` flag in .htaccess context will stop the current cycle of rewrites. Rewriting will not stop until no rules match, it encounters a rule with the `[END]` flag or something gets rewritten to the same url.

Comment: Yes, but the first rule does match for the given URL. I am now thinking that not htaccess, but Wordpress (which is running under "/community") does return the 404 - but how can that be?